# Date Formatting using only date and month?

Tags: android, simpledateformat, android-date

I need to construct a date which will display only day and month example:- 23 Dec . I have day value and month value only but how do I use SimpleDateFormat to construct a formatted date with format like "dd-MMM".How do I modified the below method to return the formatted date?

```
public String formatDate(String day, String month, String year) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM");
    }
```

Suppose if I call above method like formatDate("11","1","") then it should return me "11 Jan".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

The year value is set to 0 since you do not have it but you can pass that in to the set method.

```
public String formatDate(String day, String month, String year) {
  // Do something with the date chosen by the user
  SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM");

  Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
  c.set(0, Integer.parseInt(month)-1, Integer.parseInt(day));
  return df.format(c.getTimeInMillis());
```

}

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
MonthDay.of( Month.JANUARY , 23 )
        .toString()
```

…or…

```
MonthDay.of( Month.JANUARY , 23 )
        .format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd MMM" ) )
```

## `MonthDay`

If you want to represent a month and day-of-month without any year, use the `MonthDay` class. Built just for that purpose.

The standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format for a month and day is "--MM-DD". Similar to the date format of "YYYY-MM-DD" but with a hyphen replacing the year.

The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating Strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern for such strings. For your custom format, we must define a formatter. I suggest sticking with the ISO 8601 formats whenever possible.

```
MonthDay md = MonthDay.of( 12 , 23 );
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMM" );
String output = md.format( f );
```

> md.toString(): --12-23
>
> output: 23-Dec

See [live code in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/HWylem).

Your Question contradicts itself, at one point showing a hyphen in your desired format but in another, a SPACE. If you want the SPACE, use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd MMM" )`.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).